# how to pass Data from getters to main method in java?

Tags: java

I have written a java class with getters  and setters . And I want to store that data in a text file So I made another java class with the main method.
But I'm getting input as null.Can someone recognize my mistake and remake it?

**here is my code**

```
 package Test;
 import static java.lang.System.out;
 public class NewClass2 {

private  String[] today = new String[4];
private  int[] time = new int[4];


NewClass2() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

public  int[] gettime(){
    return time;
}
public void settime(int[] time){
    this.time = time;
}
public  String[] gettoday(){
    return today;
}
public void settoday(String[] today){
    this.today = today;
}
public void printData(){
    out.printf("%s", (Object) today);
    out.printf("%d", (Object) time);

}
}


package Test;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
public class NewClass4 {

 public static void main(String args[])throws IOException {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("google1.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    NewClass2 mynewclass=new NewClass2();
    String[] todaynew=mynewclass.gettoday();
    int[] timenew=mynewclass.gettime();
     for (int i=0; i <4; i++) {
         try{
        bw.write(todaynew[i]+"  ");
        bw.write(timenew[i]);
        bw.write("hello");
        bw.newLine();
         }
         catch(IOException e){

    }
 }


try
{
    if ( bw != null)
    bw.close( );
    fw.close( );
}
catch ( IOException e)
{
}
}
```

Comment: What on earth is going on in your `NewClass2` constructor?

Comment: Also never ever silently swallow exceptions - always print them out

Comment: yes its compiling and it's getting printed "hello" an d null

Comment: Take care of Java naming convention. First character after get and set must be uppercase

Comment: But why are you throwing UnsupportedOperationException from the constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a very quick answer, but I hope it leads you in the right direction:

**Data class**

```
    public class Data {

    private String date;
    private int time;

    public Data(String date, int time) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }
}
```

**WriteToFile class**

```
public class WriteToFile {

    public static Data data;

    public void writeToFileExample() {

        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        try {
            File file = new File("google1.txt");
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(data.getDate() + " " + data.getTime());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if(bw != null) 
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.close();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
         System.out.println("\n Written into file succesfully");       
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        data = new Data("Tuesday", 12);
        WriteToFile wtf = new WriteToFile();
        wtf.writeToFileExample();
    }
}
```

P.S. Getters and setters should follow camelCase convention and always indent your code when you ask questions. You can do that by selecting your code and pressing CTRL + K.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I want to pass arrays

Answer (score 1):

Three are a few issues here.

1. The constructor should not throw an exception.
2. The getters and setters should be named properly.
3. You should never swallow/hide an exception.
4. NewClass2 should be named appropriately to what if actually represents.
5. NewClass2 has two arrays which never contain any values, you just initialise the array. If you assign values to each array index things should start working.

Comment: can you make those mistake of my code . because I'm not getting how to do that